# Requires Datatype for inserting features

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geometry, wfs-t

I have imported postgis data in geoserver. In geoserver the spatial data column is displayed as MultiLineString, Does it affect when inserting features into geoserver or does it have to be explicitly defined as geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is bound to be a MultiLineString then you can only insert that type of geometry in the WFS-T requests, although LineString should be working too (we have an implicit promotion from single to multi geometries)